Error (Line 29) Expected command. Tried everything
The error is persistent at lines 32 and 26, I've tried to correct the syntax or structure issue in that part of the code. I've tried debugging by isolating the problem, checking interface elements, and running it incrementally. I've even tried completely rewriting and simplifying the code but that just moved the error at line 26, I've tried everything
globals [
  mycelium-density
  native-percentage
  drought?
  initial-mycelia
  signal-passed
]

breed [signals signal]
breed [fades fade]

patches-own [
  plant-species
  is-mycelium?
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape signals "circle"

  if drought? [ 
    set mycelium-density mycelium-density * 0.5
  ]
  
  ask patches [
    if random-float 100 < mycelium-density [
      set pcolor green
      set is-mycelium? true
    ] [
      set pcolor brown
      set is-mycelium? false
    ]
    
    if random-float 100 < native-percentage [
      set plant-species "native"
    ] [
      set plant-species "non-native"
    ]
  ]
  
  ask patches with [pxcor = min-pxcor and is-mycelium?] [
    sprout-signals 1 [ set color blue ]
  ]
  
  set initial-mycelia count patches with [is-mycelium?]
  set signal-passed 0
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if not any? signals [ stop ]
  
  ask signals [
    ask neighbors4 with [is-mycelium? and pcolor = green] [
      sprout-signals 1 [ set color blue ]
      set pcolor black
    ]
    set breed fades
  ]
  
  ask fades [
    set color color - 1
    if color < blue - 10 [
      set pcolor color
      die
    ]
  ]
  
  tick
end


I think you want ifelse instead of if

@LukeC, exactly right.  Both of the ifs in the ask patches block should be ifelses.  Please post your comment as an answer so I can upvote it.

In your statements like:
if random-float 100 < mycelium-density [
  set pcolor green
  set is-mycelium? true
] [
  set pcolor brown
  set is-mycelium? false
]

if is expecting a single conditional statement and then the commands to run (https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#if). If you use ifelse instead, you can provide a single conditional statement, then an 'if-true' command, then an 'if-false' command.
